# Is my code below secure enough to be used in production?

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

What is the best practice to securely upload an image to a php script based on my code below? I'm using the file transfer cordova plugin to upload the image to a php script.

Javascript (file transfer cordova plugin)

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();
params.imageLink = "test";
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "http://example.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
alert("Post Uploading");

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert(r.response);
}

function fail(error) {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    navigator.notification.alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['imageLink'])) {
$imageLink = $_POST['imageLink'];
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = $imageLink.".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], “uploads/“.$new_image_name);
}
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"?

Comment: If you want private communications between the client/server, why aren't you using TLS? (https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what to protect from:

1. Virus/threat pose as image -> use antivirus scanning before upload/save
2. Somebody snooping the packet in transmit -> use https
3. Somebody not user try to upload -> your own access control list
4. Malicous code embedded in image -> again, threat scanner

Above list is just a start though. Security is a rabbit hole that goes down deeper than what we expect it to be.